# What is the difference between text in a textbox and text outside the textbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

So in wpf xaml you can write something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Light"/>
```

But I see some people write it like this:

```
<TextBlock>Light</TextBlock>
```

Is there any difference? Why can we write in two ways? Are there any performance gains?Portability?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can we write in two ways?

It is possible to put content inside a  element for you to be able to add inlines to a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock>
     <Run>Light</Run>
     <LineBreak />
     <Run FontWeight="Bold">Bold</Run>
 </TextBlock>
```

If you however only add a string as the inner text of the TextBlock element (`<TextBlock>Light</TextBlock>`), the XAML parser will simply set the Text property of the TextBlock to this string instead of creating an Inline and adding it to the TextBlock's Inlines collection.

So there is no difference in the result, both syntaxes will set the Text property of the TextBlock to Text.

> Are there any performance gains?

No. It's just two different ways of doing the same thing basically, i.e. set the Text property of the TextBlock.

The XAML markup of a view is just a long XML based string that gets compiled into BAML when you build your application. The WPF runtime then parses the BAML tokens and creates the corresponding UI elements and set their properties when you run the application. How you have set the Text property of a TextBlock in your markup doesn't really matter at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The big difference I see is that the first option allows you to bind to something. Your text could be coming from different places, for example another control, view model etc.

Answer (score -1):

Both are same if your used normal or static(hart coded)string like your example. first one is the full form, second one is the shot cut. Otherwise if you want use the dynamic value then best way for first one through Binding. If you want to use the special characters like '&' then second one is the best way.